# Is it acceptable to answer a question and flag it as a duplicate at the same time?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

Sometimes someone asks a question that is answered more generally in a duplicate question. So I will usually flag it and leave a comment saying how they can use the answer from the duplicate question for their specific case. However sometimes I want to be more detailed. So would it be OK to flag it and add an answer describing how to use the answer for their specific problem?

Comment: Some people like to say: “A duplicate is made by the answers, not by the question.” I tend to agree in some cases. If I feel something more specific is needed to answer the question, I, personally, likely wouldn't consider it a duplicate. (Though it might still highlight lack of research from the asker.)